# Filter JSON on Nested Values?

Tags: javascript, json, filter

I've got this code here sorting, filtering, and mapping the list of all things with the type_line "Artifact". But when I try to filter by a nested value, things break down. Here's the code that works:

```
function sortByKey(array, key) {
    return array.sort(function(a, b) {
        var x = a[key]; var y = b[key];
        return ((x < y) ? -1 : ((x > y) ? 1 : 0));
    });
}

function TheCards() {
    let cardMasterList = require('./scryfall-oracle-cards.json')
    let cardMasterListSorted = sortByKey(cardMasterList, 'name')

    console.log(cardMasterList[0].name);
    console.log(cardMasterListSorted)

    return (
        <ul id="card-master-list">
                {cardMasterListSorted.filter(({type_line}) => type_line === 'Artifact').map(
                    (cardName) => {
                        return (
                            <li key={cardName.id}>
                                {cardName.name}
                            </li>
                        )
                    }
                )
            }
        </ul>
        )
}
```

If I change the filter line to this:

```
{cardMasterListSorted.filter(({legalities.vintage}) => legalities.vintage === 'legal')
```

I get an error saying it expects a comma between legalities and vintage. I'm sure it's something simple, but I'd appreciate any help!

Edit: I also just noticed the map is only showing maybe half the results? That's odd... for example, the card "Umezawa's Jitte" is missing when I filter by Artifact.

Comment: Your syntax is wrong, read about [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Unpacking_fields_from_objects_passed_as_function_parameter) on MDN. ;)

Comment: What's that mean for my issue exactly? I'm just learning all this.